# Is it valid to compute the Spearman rank correlation's p-value on summarized (mean/median) data?

Tags: time-series, correlation, p-value, mean

I have a dataset generated as follows: On each day for 30 days, a measurement is made for each individual. Individuals are separated into two groups. Each group contains 5 individuals.

Is it valid to perform the following statistical test: For each (day, group) combination, compute the mean measurement over the set of individuals. Compute the difference between group means for each day. Finally, compute the Spearman rank correlation and associated p-value between the difference in group means and the day numbering (1, 2, 3, ...).

My intuition is that this is invalid because it "hides" (or rather, ignores) the statistical variability within groups, but I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct. It just seems odd to me that the result is basically invariant to the sample size (if you assume the group means are held constant).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show with this? That the difference in group means is increasing/decreasing with time? I think the question of whether it is valid to use Spearman with the data versus whether it is appropriate to use it with this data is the issue here. Is it valid? Probably. Is it appropriate? I don't know, probably not, depends what you're trying to accomplish. Could you do what you want by computing Spearman on a scatter plot of group mean 1 vs group mean 2?

Comment: @ToddBurus I am interested in the case where the group means is increasing/decreasing with time, yes.

Comment: Is this an experimental setting with control and treatment groups, or just observations?

Comment: @ToddBurus This is an experimental setting. One group is treated and another group is not treated.

Comment: I'm most concerned about whether or not the p-value computation is "legitimate."

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to just do a start vs finish difference? Making incremental judgments on changes seems like a dangerous game. Calculating the P-value from Spearman rank would be "valid" in that the assumptions are met, but I'm not so sure it's appropriate (for various reasons, including the within group variation you mentioned).

Comment: @ToddBurus I did that (start vs. finish difference per group), the difference was not significant, and my supervisor re-analyzed the data in the manner described in my post to obtain significant p-values.

Comment: Sounds questionable to me. A significant Spearman rank shows that the there is a non-zero correlation between time and group mean difference. This doesn't really mean the same thing as having a significant change in group means differences.

Comment: @ToddBurus I agree (sounds questionable), which is why I asked this question. I'm not sure how to rigorously demonstrate this.

Comment: You may want to run an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test (or Philips-Perron test) to check for stationarity instead.

Comment: @ToddBurus Both type 2 and 3 of the ADF and PP tests are rejected with p < 0.02 in all cases. Would this suggest that the time series (of the differences in medians) is actually stationary? I notice that the result of this test is also invariant with respect to the sample sizes of the groups, which is an objection I had previously raised about the original analysis. Is this an invalid objection?

Comment: Yes. Significant results on these tests indicates stationarity. I would have to think further about it, but I believe by going the nonparametric route you shouldn't have any issue with within group variation.

Comment: @ToddBurus One more point of clarification: can you elaborate on why significant Spearman rank correlation != significant change in group means differences?

Comment: Also, aren't Spearman and Kendall rank correlation also non-parametric? Apologies if these questions are somewhat dense as I don't have any formal statistics training.

Comment: I don't have a specific example of why it doesn't work, but intuition tells me it doesn't (I could be wrong). And yes, Spearman and Kendall rank are non-parametric.

Comment: @ToddBurus I think I understand. Thanks!